# Keycard authentication with commands

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I wanted to make a keycard authentication system using the /testfor command. I want to testfor a player with a JSON book. Is this possible?

I successfully managed to test for a player (myself if it makes any difference) with stone. Instead of minecraft:stone I then tried putting minecraft:written_book {etc.}. (After the written book I pasted the part of the command here: `/give @p written_book`. Why does this not work and what have I done wrong?

Comment: So you are using different written books to be used as different keycards and you are trying to use testfor to test specific players inventory for the correct written book?  I recommend adding the commands you are using.  Including the written book give commands and the testfor commands you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Item, entity and effect names have recommended adding *minecraft:* to them since they were implemented, and now require it. If you press Tab in the command prompt, it will automatically be added.